# Postman convert cUrl to query (import doesn't work)

Tags: curl, postman

I have problem while trying to convert cURL (oauth2) below to postman query

```
curl https://ssl.xxxxx.xxxx/auth/oauth/token --data
'grant_type=client_credentials' --user
xxxclient_idxxxxx:xxxxxclient_secretxxxx
```

Do you have any solution how to convert it to postman query. I've tried import option but It didn't work. cURL in terminal works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Import this `cURL`

```
curl https://xxxclient_idxxxxx:xxxxxclient_secretxxxx@ssl.xxxxx.xxxx/auth/oauth/token --data
'grant_type=client_credentials'
```

The `--user` needs to passed into the URL `protocol://username:password@host:port`